# how to transform tab structure to accordion in a responsive ui

Tags: css, tabs, accordion, responsive-design

I am trying to design responsive ui for a php based website, and now there is a tab structure in the website where it loads data into a single data container by passing php variables through url while clicking on different tabs. **But now i need to transform the tab based structure to an accordion in lower resolution devices**. Is there any possible way.

Sample code of my tab structure is,

```
<div id="ddTabs">
<ul id="glowingTabs">
   <li>tab1</li>
   <li>tab2</li>
   <li>tab3</li>
   <li>tab4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="dataContainer">
   Data changes here...
</div>
```

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/tabs-accordion/discussion/2906434

Comment: Oops: http://codecanyon.net/item/tabs-accordion/2906434 this is the only one I found that works with tabs and then turns into an accordion at your break points.